# How to get a refresh token using the Microsoft Graph Javascript client library?

Tags: node.js, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am using the **Microsoft graph Javascript** client library to get a refresh token for a user. I created an app that connects doctors and patients. I want to create and delete events on the doctors' calendars. I first need their authorization to access their outlook account. Unfortunately, when I make the api call to get the refresh token, I get back an access token and an id token but no refresh token. Can someone please help?

Here's my code

```
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: process.env.OUTLOOK_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
        authority: process.env.OUTLOOK_OAUTH_AUTHORITY,
        clientSecret: process.env.OUTLOOK_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
                console.log(message);
            },
            piiLoggingEnabled: false,
            logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
        }
    }
};

// Create msal application object
const ouathClient = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

const response = await ouathClient.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest);
```

I am using **node js**.

Answer (score 0):

This method can also be used to get the refresh token, Please refer this Microsoft documentation.[To get refresh token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#example-1)

Comment: What is a tenant and where do I get it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can get the Tenant ID from the azure portal in App Overview page

Answer (score 0):

[Client Credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) does not support user context thus no refresh token is supported in this case.

If you are using MSAL depending on whether you are using Public client (Mobile, Desktop or Single Page apps) where users sign-in to your app then you may need a refresh token and you should be using flows listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows)

If you are using a private client like a serveside daemon then you dont need a refresh token.